# Global instances of class (across multiple files)

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am working on a project in C::B and need to use global instances of classes, across the multiple project files. (I'm new to usage of header files and global classes)
I have declared, defined, initialized classes and functions thus:

//in complex.h

```
class Julia
{
    public:
    double R;
    double I;
    void algorithm();
};
Julia J;
```

//in complex.cpp

```
#include "complex.h"
void Julia::algorithm()
{ 
    //fn body here
}
```

//in main.cpp

```
#include"complex.h"
int main()
{
    //calls initialize() and display()
}

void initialize()
{
    //...some code(irrelevant)
    cin>>J.R>>J.I;
}

void display()
{
    J.algorithm();
    //some more (irrelevant) code
}
```

On building and running the code, I get the error- "first defined here" and the Build log shows :

obj\Debug\complex.o:complex.cpp:(.bss+0x3bf0): multiple definition of `J'
obj\Debug\main.o:C:/Users/ShA/Documents/etf_build/main.cpp:20: first defined here

[This is for my 12th grade school project, and I don't think I would be allowed to use singletons (restrictions), even though they seem to be suitable. ]

Can somebody point out the possible errors in the code and how to find a solution to the errors I'm getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration

```
Julia J;
```

in your header is a *definition* of `J`, and via inclusion of the header you have this definition in two translation units: the `main.cpp` translation unit and the `complex.cpp` translation unit.

The linker doesn't know that they're (were intended to be) the same definition.

As the linker sees it, it's two separate and conflicting definitions of the same thing.

---

A purely *technical* solution is to make `J` a singleton, and a simple way to do to that is via a `static` variable in a function, which is called a “Meyers' singleton”:

```
inline
auto J()
    -> Julia&
{
    static Julia the_object;
    return the_object;
}
```

---

The technical solution above is ungood because the singleton, like the direct global variable, introduces complex arbitrary lines of communication, e.g. as via your `init` function.

There is an even more ungood possible technical solution of declaring the variable as `extern` in the header, and defining it in the corresponding implementation file. That's extra ungood because in the more general case it runs the risk of using the variable uninitialized. That's called the “static initialization order fiasco”, and is discussed in the C++ FAQ.

Instead of these technical workarounds you should change the design and let `main` create the `Julia` instance.

It can be passed down to invoked functions.

If you find that it's passed to a number of functions, in particular as a first argument, then maybe these functions should be member functions of the `Julia` class, or maybe you should then introduce a new class for this.

Comment: So according to what you recommend, `main` creates the instance, passes it on, etc, but the class remains global [and not the instance]?

Comment: @Sh.a Yes. But this is contextual advice. When you get more familiar with that way of structuring things you'll get into coding up larger and larger systems, and then you'll find that this "main" controller function is a pattern that's repeated at small scales throughout the system, but that the system itself is structured in more egalitarian fashion. Bertrand Meyer said it like this: "real systems have no top". But he was talking about larger systems in that book, and my students refused to use the book, probably because he didn't show a "main" until page 400 or so... :)

Answer (score 1):

> in complex.h
>
> `Julia J;`

This is your error. Any source file that #includes complex.h has its own version of `J`. This violates the [one definition rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

If the only place you are using the global variable `J` is in your `int main`, there is no reason to make that variable global. Make `J` a local variable inside your main function. Declaring a global variable that is used in only one place is just wrong.

On the other hand, if you are using that variable in multiple files, what you are doing is also wrong.  In this case, your `complex.h` header file should qualify your variable `J` with the `extern` keyword. Now you can reference that global in multiple places (but beware the [static initialization fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html)). You can reference that variable in multiple places. You need to define that variable in exactly one place.

Comment: Mentioning the static initialization order fiasco and yet advocating a simple global variable is inconsistent. Anyway that's ungood advice.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf -- I specifically said "beware". If a simple global variable suffices, use it. If this causes initialization order problems, don't. It's that simple. You tend to over-complicate things. Personally, I would hate (and loathe) to be the maintainer of your code. That said, I would also hate to be the maintainer of the code I myself write.

Comment: The idea that avoiding simple novice errors is to "overcomplicate" is baffling to me. I'd hate to maintain your code. And I've maintained some pretty ugly code in my time. That said, creating potential bug-attractors can be part of job security. So it all depends on the purpose.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf -- The idea that one should always invoke general relativity and graduate level quantum mechanics even to solve a simple block sliding down a ramp problem is baffling to me.

Comment: So, other than the `extern` keyword missing, the rest of the code syntax looks pretty much okay? Because,  after declaring it as `extern` in complex.h , there's an error in `main` that says "undefined reference to J"

Comment: @Sh.A - Declaring `extern Julia J` in your complex.h simply means that a global variable named `J` of type `Julia` exists somewhere. With this declaration, multiple compilation units can reference that global variable. The linker will resolve all of those multiple external references to the single definition of that global variable. If you have multiple definitions, you have violated the One Definition Rule. If you have no definition, you have an undefined reference. There needs to be one, and exactly one, definition of that variable somewhere.

Comment: @DavidHammen - Thanks, that was helpful:)

Answer (score 0):

Place a `static Julia& GetInstance()` function inside your `class Julia` declaration (in the header file).

Place an instance of the `Julia` (`Julia J`) inside the source file.  Then inside the `GetInstance()` implementation (also in the source file), return `J`.

Complex.h

```
class Julia
{
    public:
    double R;
    double I;
    void algorithm();
    static Julia& getInstance();
};
```

Complex.c

```
#include "complex.h"
Julia J;
void Julia::algorithm()
{ 
    //fn body here
}
Julia& Julia::getInstance() { return J; }
```

Comment: But make sure you initialize all your variables please.

Comment: You could even create a `static Julia J;` instance in the class header file, and initialize it in the source file.